# How can I use iloc to extract rows of a dataframe to create a separate dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, append

I have a dataframe from which I would like to extract specific rows and create a separate dataframe consisting of those extracted rows.

The following is an example:

df =

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | red | blue | yellow |
| 1 | monago | orange | apple |
| 2 | five | six | seven |

I have the row indices in an array called row_ind with values (0,2):

```
for i in range(len(df))
    a = row_ind[i]
    b = df.iloc[a]
```

How can I use this to create the data set that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = []

for i in range(len(df))
    a = row_ind[i]
    foo.append(a)

newdf = df.iloc[foo]
```